# Openpyxl: Adding A List Number To a "Delete List" List If Current Sheet Value Does Not Match A Value

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm reading through an excel spreadsheet trying to delete rows who's first column values don't match "36.0 ∞C" or "0.0 ∞C".  Right now I'm trying to just create a list of rows to delete so after I create a list of all the temperature values in the temperature column ("temperatureList") I can delete the rows that are in the "deleteCellList" list.  Here's my code:

```
temperatureList = []
deleteCellList = []
tempRowNumber = 1

while currentRowValue:
    currentRowValue = sheet[(f"B{tempRowNumber}")].value
    print(type(currentRowValue))
    print("Current Row Value")
    print(currentRowValue)
    if currentRowValue != "0.0 ∞C":
        deleteCellList.append(tempRowNumber)
    elif currentRowValue != "18.0 ∞C":
        deleteCellList.append(tempRowNumber)
    else:
        temperatureList.append(currentRowValue)
    tempRowNumber += 1

print("DCL")
print(deleteCellList)
```

The problem I find I'm running into is that this algorithm is adding all of the cells where there should be maybe 5-6 values here, as shown by the following output:

How it's not supposed to look:
DCL
[1,2,3,4.....]

I'm trying to make it look like this:

DCL
[45, 78, 203, 408]

I've tried printing each cell value, which returns something like "36.0 ∞C" so I don't think there are any rogue spaces that should be screwing it up.  That being said, I've tried everything I know up to this point, any intuitions out there on what the potential problem/solution could be here?

Answer (score 0):

Two clarifications to get out of the way:

1. You use 36.0 in the question, but 18.0 in the code sample- I'm assuming the 18.0 in the code sample is correct
2. You reference "the first column" value, but "B" is the second column, so I'm assuming that you are using a table that's shifted over one column.

Beyond those two, the issue is how you are applying your if-logic:

```
if currentRowValue != "0.0 ∞C":          ## If a value does not equal "0.0 ∞C"
    deleteCellList.append(tempRowNumber)
elif currentRowValue != "18.0 ∞C":       ## Otherwise (if the value DOES equal "0.0 ∞C"), if the value does not equal "18.0 ∞C"
    deleteCellList.append(tempRowNumber)
else:                                    ## Otherwise (if the value equals "0.0 ∞C" and also equals "18.0 ∞C")
    temperatureList.append(currentRowValue)
```

So, for example values of "0.0 ∞C","18.0 ∞C", and "1000.0001 ∞C":

- "0.0 ∞C" => Fails (== "0.0 ∞C") => Passes (!= "18.0 ∞C") so add to deleteCellList
- "18.0 ∞C" => Passes (!= "0.0 ∞C") so add to deleteCellList
- "1000.0001 ∞C" => Passes (!= "0.0 ∞C") so add to deleteCellList

What you're trying to do is check for values *not in* a list of acceptable values, so the easiest fix is to change the logic to reflect that:

```
if currentRowValue not in ["0.0 ∞C","18.0 ∞C"]:
    deleteCellList.append(tempRowNumber)
else:
    temperatureList.append(currentRowValue)
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: derp, that makes complete sense.  Will try this out and report back, thank you so much for the catch.  Also my apologies for not stating the problem completely accurately: Definitely a case of staring at the code for too long that I was overloading my brain trying to describe it after looking at it for so long.

Comment: Checking back in on whether that fixed your problem or if you need further help.